# socket.io and node.js: set the port when I parse the url to get a query string value?

Tags: node.js, apache, sockets, websocket, socket.io

My apache server of xampp runs on port 80 by default and nodejs as defined by me on port 1337: `http.listen(1337)`. That's why I cant see my website when I open `http://localhost:1337`, because I have to use the port 80 to see my apache files. So I can see it only with `http://localhost:80`

And I want to parse a url to pass it as a variable to my node.js-server. That's my problem. Is there a way to tell **socket.io or the node.js-server** to get/parse the url of the specific port 80?

I want to get the value of the query string "**id**" that way.

This is my code so far (doesn't work that way):

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var parts = require('url').parse(socket.handshake.url + ":80/customname/",true).parts;
    console.log('socket-url: ' + parts.id);
```

Also maybe important to mention: I get the value `null` when I display the port of this parsed url when I'm replacing `.parts` with `.port` at line 2 of this code.

Comment: I really don't understand what kind of setup you're trying to make work.  Why  do you have an Apache server and a node.js server?  What are their roles in your application?  Are you trying to use node.js only for socket.io?  What top level problem are you trying to solve in the your `connection` handler?  You appear to be asking about an implementation detail without describing the overall goal of what you're building which makes it very hard for us to know what the best solution might be.

Comment: FYI, a normal socket.io connection URL looks like this: `http://yourdomain.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1429374210134-0`, it doesn't contain your own query parameters.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting how server port binding works. Tell us the big picture - how are you planning to use `socket.io` on your website?